# Automatically line break a string in a specific lenght

Tags: javascript

Im having a problem in Front end. Where the user comment a string.

> "WAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"

without a space. This issue cause my web to exceed the text in the layout or much worse in the mobile browser.
So im thinking if there's a way to insert a "\n" or < br > when the string.lenght > my.lenght. When true break a line?

Comment: yeah but it is implemented in css

Comment: the function of "substr_replace" is what im talking about in js.. if there's any same function in js?

Comment: @FlashProgrammer why are you trying to do this in javascript? Whatever solution you come up with will not automatically flow with the container for your text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess a fast solution would be using a regexp:

```
//javascript
"12345678".split(/(.{2})/).slice(1, -1).join("<BR>");
//output = 12<BR><BR>34<BR><BR>56<BR><BR>78
```

With here {2} the number of character between each jump.

Comment: This is what im looking :) thanks bro.. i will accept this question after 5mins.. Thank you so much Yacine! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can solve this with CSS much easier.

The [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) property allows you to define a display behavior for exceptionally long words.

Click <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> to see the results

```css
p {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}

p.notbroken {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<!-- broken -->
<p>
watch out for the really long word WAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ok it's over
</p>

<!-- fixed -->
<p class="notbroken">
watch out for the really long word WAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ok it's over
</p>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but im looking for js code.. Since before getting the json date i will line break all the comment before posting in different division. But this perfectly works when i implemented that class and automatically break a word

Comment: I have no idea what you just said but I would bet you're doing it wrong

Answer (score 0):

A javascript solution for you.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b7grep1v/1/

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('test');
var myString = "WAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA1";

if (myString.length > 10) {
    var index = 0,
        length = myString.length,
        chunk = 10;
    for (; index < length; index += chunk) {
        myDiv.textContent += myString.slice(index, index + chunk) + "\n";
    }
}
```